# Python datastructure with string for indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-structures

I'm quite new to Python and I am looking for a datastructure to store results from measurements with different parameters.

I have two parameters, `param_1_vals = [10, 20, 30, 40]` and `param_2_vals = [1, 2, 3, 4]` with which I do some caluculations and finally obtain a result `result`, which is a Numpy array. Since I loop through the parameters in nested `for` oops, for each combination of parameters I get a different `result` array.

I wonder if there is a multidimensional datastructure that is able to store all the results for all parameter combinations can be indexed like

```
 result_(param_1,param_2)
```

which gives me the corresponding Numpy array for that specific combination of parameters.
Preferably, the parameters can not only be numeric but also strings.

Comment: take a look at [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small input arrays, the simplest solution is probably to use a 2D array with row indexes from the first input array and column indexes from the second input array:

```
result = numpy.empty((len(param_1_vals),len(param_2_vals)))
result[i,j] = yourCalculation(param_1_vals[i],param_2_vals[j])
```

It is more elegant (and more efficient for large datasets) to store your results in a dictionary with a tuple of input values as keys:

```
result = {}
result[(a,b)] = yourCalculation(a,b)
```

You can also use the indexes as dictionary keys if `a` and `b` are floats or mutable variables.

```
result = {}
result[(i,j)] = yourCalculation(param_1_vals[i],param_2_vals[j])
```

In general, what you're trying to achieve is [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries),  a key-value datastructure

```
result_ = {}
```

foreach combination param_1,param_2
form a tuple t = (param_1,param_2) and use it as key

```
result_[t]= result
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as the more elegant solution @leeladam suggested?